# Vertical fade and different color on horizontal

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, fragment, gradient

How can we create linear gradient with different colors and fade from top to bottom (vertical fading) with `qml` or `javascript`?

Or can with `fragment`? is there any tutorial!!

In other words, combine two images.

[image]

[image]

---

**UPDATE**:
I draw this with illustrator and exactly what I want.

[image]

Comment: The images supplied don't really match the description

Comment: I mean merge 2 image together because I didn't find my main about problem image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to solve your issue is already mentioned in my first answer. Please have a read and try to understand the code.

I made another example that does what you want with `OpacityMask`, if you want to do it with shaders take my example from [github](https://github.com/iam-peter/stackoverflow/tree/main/questions/75623151) to make your shader work and then read about GLSL. There is no tutorial in Qt that teaches you about fragment shaders as it is just using GLSL. The only difficult part with shaders in QML is to make them work, but as said before you can copy my example from github or any other and adapt it.

You should read about [OpacityMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) and [LinearGradient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-lineargradient.html).

If you want to know more about shaders in QML you should read about [ShaderTools](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtshadertools-build.html), [ShaderEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html) and [ShaderEffectSource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html).

[image]

```
LinearGradient {
    id: mask
    anchors.fill: parent
    start: Qt.point(0, 0)
    end: Qt.point(0, root.height)
    visible: false
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "black" }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "transparent" }
    }
}

LinearGradient {
    id: gradientSource
    anchors.fill: parent
    start: Qt.point(0, 0)
    end: Qt.point(root.width, 0)
    visible: false
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "yellow" }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "red" }
    }
}

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
/*
    Image { // transparency checkerboard
        anchors.fill: parent
        fillMode: Image.Tile
        source: "qrc:/images/checkers.png"
    }
*/
    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: gradientSource
        maskSource: mask
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my quest with new image!

Comment: I've updated the answer to fit your issue.

Comment: Thx, but don't need to using `Image`

Comment: Remove the image...it's just there to show you the transparency.

Answer (score 3):

From your question I assume you want to merge two images together with some sort of fading from one to the other?

I've used [OpacityMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) and [LinearGradient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-lineargradient.html) which are both part of the [Qt 5 Compatibility API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html). Depending on the Qt version you're using you can either use:

- Qt 5 [OpacityMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) and [LinearGradient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-lineargradient.html)
- Qt 6 [OpacityMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) and [LinearGradient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-lineargradient.html)
- Qt 6.5 [MultiEffect](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.5/qml-qtquick-effects-multieffect.html) and [Gradient](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.5/qml-qtquick-gradient.html)

The example works as follows:

1. Create a `LinearGradient` that goes from black to transparent which is used as the mask.
2. Load two images (if you don't want to see the original you should hide them with `visible: false`).
3. Create two `OpacityMask` instances on top of each other which both have the same mask applied (bottom is using `invert: true`) and a different source image.

I would also suggest using custom [shaders](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html) in order to achieve that effect, because it will be quicker and not as redundant as drawing the `OpacityMask` twice.

---

**Edit:** I've added the mentioned `ShaderEffect` and the accompanying fragment shader. The result is a bit different to the `OpacityMask` solution, but this might also be due to the GLSL `mix()` function the example is using.

My example is using Qt 6.4.0 you can get the complete source from [here](https://github.com/iam-peter/stackoverflow/tree/main/questions/75623151).

[image]

```
import QtQuick
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 940
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    readonly property int _width: 200
    readonly property int _height: 300

    LinearGradient {
        id: mask
        width: root._width
        height: root._height
        start: Qt.point(0, 0)
        end: Qt.point(0, root._height)
        visible: false
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "black" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "transparent" }
        }
    }

    Grid {
        columns: 3
        spacing: 20

        Image {
            id: imgSourceTop
            source: "https://picsum.photos/id/54/%1/%2".arg(root._width).arg(root._height)
            smooth: true
        }

        Image {
            id: imgSourceBottom
            source: "https://picsum.photos/id/93/%1/%2".arg(root._width).arg(root._height)
            smooth: true
        }

        Item {
            width: root._width
            height: root._height

            OpacityMask {
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: imgSourceTop
                maskSource: mask
            }

            OpacityMask {
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: imgSourceBottom
                maskSource: mask
                invert: true
            }
        }

        LinearGradient {
            id: gradientSourceTop
            width: root._width
            height: root._height
            start: Qt.point(0, 0)
            end: Qt.point(root._width, 0)
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#1E9600" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "#FFF200" }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#FF0000" }
            }
        }

        LinearGradient {
            id: gradientSourceBottom
            width: root._width
            height: root._height
            start: Qt.point(0, 0)
            end: Qt.point(root._width, 0)
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#833ab4" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "#fd1d1d" }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#fcb045" }
            }
        }

        Item {
            width: root._width
            height: root._height

            OpacityMask {
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: gradientSourceTop
                maskSource: mask
            }

            OpacityMask {
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: gradientSourceBottom
                maskSource: mask
                invert: true
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: shaderSourceTop
            source: "https://picsum.photos/id/54/%1/%2".arg(root._width).arg(root._height)
            smooth: true
        }

        Image {
            id: shaderSourceBottom
            source: "https://picsum.photos/id/93/%1/%2".arg(root._width).arg(root._height)
            smooth: true
        }

        ShaderEffect {
            width: root._width
            height: root._height
            property variant sourceTop: shaderSourceTop
            property variant sourceBottom: shaderSourceBottom
            fragmentShader: "shaders/blend.frag.qsb"
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
#version 440

layout(location = 0) in vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D sourceTop;
layout(binding = 2) uniform sampler2D sourceBottom;

layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform buf {
    mat4 qt_Matrix;
    float qt_Opacity;
};

void main()
{
    vec4 top = texture(sourceTop, qt_TexCoord0);
    vec4 bottom = texture(sourceBottom, qt_TexCoord0);
    fragColor = mix(top, bottom, qt_TexCoord0.y);
}
```

Comment: Thx, but I want to draw with `Gradient`, second my Image with different color in horizontal not single color.  Where is tutorial of `fragment`?

Comment: What tutorial are you talking about? Fragment shader?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the fragment shader could solve it, but I have only bits and pieces of information about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you're asking, but, I tried to recreate your images using QML. The second image I used a tiled SVG image as a base, then, on top I use a LinearGradient but I set the opacity so I can see the base partially:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
Page {
    id: page
    ColumnLayout {
        Frame {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 500
            Layout.preferredHeight: 300
            LinearGradient {
                anchors.fill: parent
                start: Qt.point(0, 0)
                end: Qt.point(width, 0)
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "yellow" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "purple" }
                }
            }
        }
        Frame {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 300
            Layout.preferredHeight: 300
            padding: 0
            Image {
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: "squares.svg"
                fillMode: Image.Tile
            }
            LinearGradient {
                anchors.fill: parent
                start: Qt.point(0, height)
                end: Qt.point(0, 0)
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "white" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "blue" }
                }
                opacity: 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}

// squares.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="16" height="16" fill="#ccc"/>
<rect x="16" y="0" width="16" height="16" fill="#eee"/>
<rect x="0" y="16" width="16" height="16" fill="#eee"/>
<rect x="16" y="16" width="16" height="16" fill="#ccc"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)